# Salesforce 'Cases' to Zendesk 'Tickets'

Tags: salesforce, zendesk

I have many 'cases' on Salesforce, but I will no longer use him.

For this reason I need export them to Zendesk.

But i didn't find a solution, the options offered by Zendesk are for 'Account', 'Contact' and 'Leads' but not found to 'Cases'.

Has anyone gone through this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems, [Workato](https://www.workato.com) might be able to help with your case.